# Derivation optical depth cloud of atoms

Tags: atomic-physics

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_depth#Formulations), *"the optical depth $\tau$ of a cloud of atoms is given by
$$
\tau = \frac{d^2 \nu N} {2 c \hbar \epsilon_0 A \gamma},
$$
where $d$ denotes the transition dipole moment, $\gamma$ the natural linewidth of the transition, $\nu$ the frequency, $N$ the number of atoms, and $A$ the cross-section of the beam".*

I have tried finding a derivation of this formula, but I cannot. Can anyone provide me with a good reference for this, or maybe give me the highlights of its derivation?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of optical depth is $\tau = n \sigma x$, where $n$ is a number density, $\sigma$ is the absorption cross-section and $x$ a distance travelled. If the beam has area $A$, then $n x = N/A$.

So the question boils down to can one show that 
$$\sigma =  \frac{d^2 \nu}{2 c \hbar \epsilon_0 \gamma}$$

If we take the classical cross-section
$$\sigma_c = \left[\frac{\gamma/2\pi}{(\omega - \omega_{ij})^2 + \gamma^{2}/4}\right] \left(\frac{\pi e^2}{2\epsilon_0 m_e c}\right) $$

The actual cross-section is given by this multiplied by the oscillator strength $f_{ij}$.

If $d$ is the modulus of the electric dipole matrix element for the transition(?), then I believe that
$$f_{ij} = \frac{8 \pi^2 m_e \nu_{ij}}{3e^2 h} d^2$$

This gives (assuming we take the case of $\omega = \omega_{ij}$)
$$ \sigma = f_{ij} \sigma_c = \left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)\left[\frac{d^2 \nu}{c \hbar \epsilon_0 \gamma}\right]     $$

So I am "out" by a factor $8\pi/3$.

Pointing out flaws in my calculation would be greatly appreciated, as I've been staring at this for an hour and I'm beginning to suspect there *could* be an error on the wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/OpticalDepth.html (the reference given at the bottom of the Wiki article) the optical depth is given by

$$\tau =  N \sigma$$

where $N$ is the *column density* and $\sigma$ is the *cross section*. There is a helpful discussion of the mathematics of the cross section [in this document](http://www.doylegroup.harvard.edu/wiki/images/f/f4/Hilborn.pdf). Equation (34) in that document looks like it might reduce to the one you have above in the limit where $\omega = \omega_0$ - although I admit I didn't work through the details. Some useful references in that document as well - in particular their ref. 2: A.Corney, Atomic and Laser Spectroscopy (Clarendon, Oxford, 1977).

Comment: Yes, this is definitely an on-resonance approximation. This is also likely derived for a cold atom cloud which is quite different from a standard optical vapor (such as a Rubidium cell). The warm vapor has doppler broadening and other temperature dependence. For cold atom stuff, look for Laser Cooling and Trapping by Metcalf and van der Straten.